# Greatest Common Divisor multiplicative proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Given : gcd(m,n) = 1 , gcd(d<sub>1</sub>,d<sub>2</sub>) = 1.
Show : gcd(m,d<sub>1</sub>)*gcd(n,d<sub>2</sub>) = gcd(mn,d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>2</sub>).

> Is my proof for above correct ?
>   If no , what have I missed ?
>   If yes , is there any better way to prove it ?

Proof :

> p<sub>i</sub> , q<sub>i</sub> , e<sub>i</sub> , f<sub>i</sub> are prime numbers.
>
> m = p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup>....p<sub>s</sub><sup>k<sub>s</sub></sup>...p<sub>w</sub><sup>k<sub>w</sub></sup>
>   d<sub>1</sub> = p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>....p<sub>s</sub><sup>a<sub>s</sub></sup> e<sub>s+1</sub><sup>b<sub>s+1</sub></sup> ...e<sub>x</sub><sup>a<sub>x</sub></sup>
>   n = q<sub>1</sub><sup>l<sub>1</sub></sup>q<sub>2</sub><sup>l<sub>2</sub></sup>....q<sub>t</sub><sup>l<sub>t</sub></sup> q<sub>t+1</sub><sup>b<sub>t+1</sub></sup> ...q<sub>y</sub><sup>l<sub>y</sub></sup>
>   d<sub>2</sub> = q<sub>1</sub><sup>g<sub>1</sub></sup>q<sub>2</sub><sup>g<sub>2</sub></sup>....q<sub>t</sub><sup>g<sub>t</sub></sup> f<sub>t+1</sub><sup>g<sub>t+1</sub></sup> ...f<sub>z</sub><sup>g<sub>z</sub></sup>
>
> gcd(m,d<sub>1</sub>) = p<sub>1</sub><sup>min(k<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>)</sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>min(k<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>)</sup>...p<sub>s</sub><sup>min(k<sub>s</sub>,a<sub>s</sub>)</sup>
>   gcd(n,d<sub>2</sub>) = q<sub>1</sub><sup>min(l<sub>1</sub>,g<sub>1</sub>)</sup>q<sub>2</sub><sup>min(l<sub>2</sub>,g<sub>2</sub>)</sup>...q<sub>t</sub><sup>min(l<sub>t</sub>,g<sub>t</sub>)</sup>
>   mn = p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup>....p<sub>s</sub><sup>k<sub>s</sub></sup>...p<sub>w</sub><sup>k<sub>w</sub></sup>q<sub>1</sub><sup>l<sub>1</sub></sup>q<sub>2</sub><sup>l<sub>2</sub></sup>....q<sub>t</sub><sup>l<sub>t</sub></sup> q<sub>t+1</sub><sup>b<sub>t+1</sub></sup> ...q<sub>y</sub><sup>l<sub>y</sub></sup>
>   d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>2</sub> = p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub>a<sub>2</sub>....p<sub>s</sub><sup>a<sub>s</sub></sup> e<sub>s+1</sub><sup>b<sub>s+1</sub></sup> ...e<sub>x</sub><sup>a<sub>x</sub></sup>q<sub>1</sub><sup>g<sub>1</sub></sup>q<sub>2</sub><sup>g<sub>2</sub></sup>....q<sub>t</sub><sup>g<sub>t</sub></sup> f<sub>t+1</sub><sup>g<sub>t+1</sub></sup> ...f<sub>z</sub><sup>g<sub>z</sub></sup>
>   gcd(mn , d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>2</sub>) = q<sub>1</sub><sup>min(l<sub>1</sub>,g<sub>1</sub>)</sup>q<sub>2</sub><sup>min(l<sub>2</sub>,g<sub>2</sub>)</sup>...q<sub>t</sub><sup>min(l<sub>t</sub>,g<sub>t</sub>)</sup>p<sub>1</sub><sup>min(k<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>)</sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>min(k<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>)</sup>...p<sub>s</sub><sup>min(k<sub>s</sub>,a<sub>s</sub>)</sup>
>
> gcd(mn , d<sub>1</sub>d<sub>2</sub>) = gcd(m, d<sub>1</sub>)*gcd(n, d<sub>2</sub>)

Please do confirm if it is correct.

Sorry for the title , not appropriate.

Comment: You *must* use MathJax for typing. Please change it.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I am sorry , I don't know how to use it ? Is the question not visible clearly ?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The second line said that you want to prove $\gcd(mn,d_1,d_2)$, but your proof shows that you prove $\gcd(mn,d_1d_2)$!

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio thanks for noticing. Rectified

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false so your proof cannot be correct, e.g. put $\, m> 1\,$ below

$$\begin{align} 
(m,d_1)(n,d_2) &= (m\cdot n,\, d_1\cdot  d_2)\\[.3em]
1 = (m,1)\,(1,m)\, &\neq (m\cdot 1,\,1\cdot m) = m\end{align}\qquad$$

To debug your proof put $\,m=2\,$ above and find the first line in your proof that fails for these values.

**Remark** $\ $ Generally if $\, (m,n) = 1 = (d_1,d_2)\,$ then we have

$$(mn,d_1 d_2) = (m,d_1 d_2) (n,d_1d_2) = (m,d_1)\color{#c00}{(m,d_2) (n,d_1)}(n,d_2)\qquad $$

and the latter $= (m,d_1) (n,d_2) \iff \color{#c00}{(m,d_2) = 1 = (n,d_1)}$

Comment: Got it , thank you.

Comment: I missed that d2 and m can have common factors.

Comment: @Aditya As can $\,\color{#c00}n$ and $\,\color{#c00}{d_1}\ \ \ $